# Can one prove the existence of a fixed point for a shrinking map on a sequentially compact metric space WITHOUT proving the space is compact?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $(X,\rho)$ be a metric space with $Y\subset X$ a sequentially compact subspace, and a mapping $T:X\to Y$ satisfying $\rho(Tx, Ty)<\rho(x,y)$ for all $x\neq y$. Prove that $T$ has a unique fixpunkt.

This is sort of a curiosity, but in the perpetual interest of economy of proof, I am wondering if there is a slick way to dither past compactness and to just get a fixed point straight from sequential compactness. I have seen the proofs of existence (uniqueness is no problem) for a shrinking map on a compact space, one of which uses compactness to guarantee nonemptiness of an infinite intersection, and the other which uses compactness to make an extreme value theorem argument. The proofs of metric space sequential compactness $\implies$ compactness via Lebesgue number lemma and similar aren't particularly neat, so I was wondering about a bypass for whatever it's worth.

Comment: Did you tried to define $x_n = T^n x_0$ for some $x_0 \in X$ and use sequential compactness on the sequence $\{x_n\}$? I don't know if this works.

Comment: "one of which uses compactness to guarantee nonemptiness of an infinite intersection" How do you use the nonemptiness of an infinite intersection to prove it?